# Trouble with C++11 regex_search

Tags: regex, c++11

I run into a very 'simple' problem I seem unable to find a solution to for the past hour.

Consider the example:
[example](https://rextester.com/EUYAX67380)

I'm trying to capture directory names (i.e any sequences of following characters that are not '\'); seems like a basic REGEX:

```
[^\/]+
```

it works in other engines; I've tried escaping '/' in various ways. other basic character groups like [a-z] doesn't seem to work for me neither.

what am I missing?
Full example:

```
int main ()
{
    const std::string rna = "./var/log/xyz/10032008.log" ;
    std::cout << "rna: " << std::quoted(rna) << '\n' ;

    const std::regex re( "[^\/]+" ) ;

    std::smatch match ;
    if( std::regex_search( rna, match, re ) )
    {
        for(int i=0;i<match.size();i++)
        {
             std::cout << match.position(i) << " found " << std::quoted( match[i].str() ) << '\n';
        }


    }

    else std::cout << "no match" ;
}
```

Comment: Post your [mcve] *in* the question itself! Links can disappear or the contents change, making the question worthless. Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What is the expected result? BTW, see https://rextester.com/PRF80639 if you need multiple matching. `regex_search` only finds the first occurrence.

Comment: I've updated with full example

Comment: This tool may help to identify problems: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Swift; thanks I already do know the tool (and many others) my students do prefer to use 101 instead of my beloved Expresso;p @Wiktor Stribiżew you were right; the problem lied not in the regex but in the fact that regex_search returns just the FIRST occurrence; I wouldn't expect that. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Expresso is great to test .NET regexps, regex101 is great to test PCRE/Python re/JS RegExp and Go regex patterns, and is good in general to debug simple patterns across all platforms and libraries.

Comment: Thank you once again Wiktor; Please provide a full answer (if you wish) so that I could accept.